# Drupal Field Validation - Get Value of the field to validate

Tags: php, validation, drupal, drupal-7

I am using the Drupal module `field_validation`.
I am trying to validate a field through the `PHP Code`, formerly `Custom PHP Function`.

The piece of code inside the validator configuration is:

```
if (!my_validator($this))
  { $this->set_error(); };
```

Where my function is:

```
function my_validator($variables) {
  $my_value = $variables->value; // Error here (the property is protected)!
  ...
```

As explained in https://www.drupal.org/node/1325068 I also tried to retrieve the variable as

```
  $my_value = $variables['value']; // Error also (variables is not an array)!
```

I tried as well `function my_validator(&$variables)`, or `->getValue()`, nothing to do.

It says the property is protected, and this error breaks the webapp.
Note that the debugger enters correctly inside the function, and also can access the value, can read it, everything. But when I try to put it inside another variable: bum!

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried the hook hook_fapi_validation_rules() in the Form API ? you can set your own validation there and a custom error message for that and attach the rule in your form element. See this link https://www.drupal.org/project/fapi_validation

Comment: I can perform my custom validation in many ways, but I would like to use the standard way when possible.